# How to read OpenCV's haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file without OpenCV in Python?

Tags: xml, opencv, haar-classifier, viola-jones

I'm trying to implement Viola-Jones algorithm from scratch in Python. However, I do not want to waste a lot of time training. So, I was thinking about using the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file to get the classifiers immediately. However, when I looked in OpenCV implementation of reading the XML file, I couldn't understand it.

I understand how Viola-Jones works (the Haar-like feature, cascaded classifiers, etc.). My problem is that I don't understand the XML file.

How can I read the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file in Python? Are there any place where I can get the weights immediately?

I tried viewing the file but some values didn't make sense to me (like the features one)